Using the none driver based on user configuration X Exiting due to GUEST_MISSING_CONNTRACK: Kubernetes 1.30.0 requires crictl to be installed in ro
not able to start minikube on ubuntu 22.04
root@ip-172-31-2-10:/home/ubuntu# apt install conntrack
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
conntrack
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 45 not upgraded.
Need to get 33.5 kB of archives.
After this operation, 104 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ap-south-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 conntrack amd64 1:1.4.6-2build2 [33.5 kB]
Fetched 33.5 kB in 0s (1348 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package conntrack.
(Reading database ... 65647 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../conntrack_1%3a1.4.6-2build2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking conntrack (1:1.4.6-2build2) ...
Setting up conntrack (1:1.4.6-2build2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Scanning processes...
Scanning linux images...
Running kernel seems to be up-to-date.
No services need to be restarted.
No containers need to be restarted.
No user sessions are running outdated binaries.
No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host.
root@ip-172-31-2-10:/home/ubuntu# minikube start --vm-driver=none

minikube v1.33.1 on Ubuntu 22.04 (xen/amd64)
Using the none driver based on user configuration

X Exiting due to GUEST_MISSING_CONNTRACK: Sorry, Kubernetes 1.30.0 requires crictl to be installed in root's path
root@ip-172-31-2-10:/home/ubuntu#

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
